# Starting Neo4j Server failed: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: windows, neo4j

After installing the Neo4J Community on Windows 8, and starting up, I get the following error:
Starting Neo4j Server failed: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
What could be causing this error?

Comment: How did you install it? With the installer or the zip download? And which version did you install?

Comment: I used the installer, neo4j-community_windows-x64_2_2_3.exe

Comment: I did find a workaround, though. I installed Java 8 (I only had Java 7 previously) and now I start up Neo4J by clicking on neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar, and this works fine. When I click on neo4j-community.exe I still get the same error, after trying to start the server.

Comment: Thanks John, I asked our team to investigate.